# How to send a Cancel action to ServiceNow Request Item via the REST API?

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

There is a *Cancel* button on our ServiceNow Request Items, when clicked it sets the *Stage* to "Request Cancelled" and *State* to "Closed Incomplete"

[image: Clicking Cancel button]

How do I achieve the same but using the ServiceNow's REST API? I've tried sending a `POST` to:

```
"$instanceURL/api/now/table/sc_req_item/$ritmSysID/cancel"
```

but get error:

```
Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Response Content: {"error":{"message":"Requested URI does not represent any resource","detail":null},"status":"failure"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to send a PATCH request to
/api/now/table/change_request/{sys-id-of-change-request}
with a payload having state as 4

{
"state": "4",
"work_notes": "Canceling change"
}